# Request with Retrofit and RxJava giving error

Tags: android, request, retrofit

I'm developing an app that in the main activity there is a viewpager, 3 tabs load the content from the webservice, when I change quickly between the tabs, one request gets the body from another request, then I get 500 internal error, because the body of request is wrong.

I'm using retrofit and rxjava to make the requests, like below:

```
CustomApplication.getApi().appointmentList("application/json", userPrefs.getToken(), appointmentFilter)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<AppointmentInstanceList>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    if (mProgressBar != null)
                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    if (mProgressBar != null)
                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    showViewNoResults();

                    String message = getString(R.string.error_request);

                    if (e != null && e instanceof RetrofitError) {
                        RetrofitError retrofitError = (RetrofitError) e;
                        if (retrofitError.getKind() == RetrofitError.Kind.NETWORK) {
                            message = getString(R.string.error_network);
                        } else if (retrofitError.getKind() == RetrofitError.Kind.HTTP) {
                            message = getString(R.string.error_network);
                        }
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(AppointmentInstanceList appointmentList) {
                    appointmentListAdapter = new AppointmentListAdapter(getActivity(), appointmentList.appointmentInstanceList);
                    if (appointmentListView != null && appointmentListAdapter != null)
                        appointmentListView.setAdapter(appointmentListAdapter);

                    showViewNoResults();
                }
            });
```

Somebody knows how to fix this?

Thanks